# Import the parallel-coordinates library(d3.js) to jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, import, jsfiddle, parallel-coordinates

I'm trying to do one of my projects with jsfiddle to be able to share it (for another question).
Here is what i've done so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/x74wemq0/3/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"       charset="utf-8"></script>
```

i already include d3.js which i need, too (posted above).
The one missing thing is an import for this library https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates but i don't finde the link which i have to use (and to be honest i don't really know how to use it correctly). Can you please tell me what's the right link, and how i have to use it or where i can learn how to (for a beginner).

---

I have already tried to:
use the github link which points to the (raw)code of the library (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates/master/d3.parcoords.js) but that didn't work (maybe i used it in a wrong way; i used it equal to the d3.js import)

---

thanks in advance
Jones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in js fiddle:

click `External Resources` on the right hand side navigation
past in your script url

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js`

click plus then add parallel-coordinates url

`https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/d3.parcoords.js`

to add the css you do the same thing but with the css url

`https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/d3.parcoords.css`

your code should then work. It's worth pointing out that you have errors in you code (on the js fiddle) these will become clear once you've sorted the lib issue

Comment: thank you very much. it works so far i think but i need the css file to, can you pleas add in your description how to get this?

Comment: cool, now it works. @atmd I get the process, but i don't get were you found this links, sorry. can you please explain it? this is the working fiddle: (https://jsfiddle.net/x74wemq0/4/). Did i get you right, you say there are mistakes in the code? i don't see any:( can you help me to improve?

Comment: found the links @atmd